# Airflow log file exception

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am using apache airflow for running my dags.

I am getting an exception as:

```
*** Log file does not exist: /opt/airflow/logs/download2/download2/2020-07-26T15:00:00+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://fb3393f5f01e:8793/log/download2/download2/2020-07-26T15:00:00+00:00/1.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. HTTPConnectionPool(host='fb3393f5f01e', port=8793): Max retries exceeded with url: /log/download2/download2/2020-07-26T15:00:00+00:00/1.log (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8ba66d7b70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

My docker compose file for webserver, scheduler and postgres is:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  postgres_airflow:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
        - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"

  postgres_Service:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=developer
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
        - POSTGRES_DB=service_db
    ports:
        - "5433:5432"
 
  scheduler:
    image: apache/airflow
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres_airflow
      - postgres_Service
      - webserver
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
        - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 30s
        retries: 3

  webserver:
    image: apache/airflow
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - pg_airflow
        - pg_metadata
        - tenants-registry-api
        - metadata-api
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
        - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
        - ./scripts:/opt/airflow/scripts
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
    entrypoint: ./scripts/airflow-entrypoint.sh
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 30s
        retries: 3
```

I am getting this exception while using the PythonVirtualenvOperator.

My dag file is:

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args = {'owner': 'airflow',
                'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 1)
                }

dag = DAG('download2',
          schedule_interval='0 * * * *',
          default_args=default_args,
          catchup=False)


def hello_world_py():
    return "data"


with dag:
    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='download2',
        python_callable=hello_world_py,
        op_kwargs=None,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
    )
```

env file:

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres_airflow:5432/airflow
AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY=XXXX
AIRFLOW_CONN_METADATA_DB=postgres://developer:secret@postgres_Service:5432/service_db
AIRFLOW__VAR__METADATA_DB_SCHEMA=service_db
AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__BASE_URL=http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

I have also explicitly set AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOGGING=False to disable the remote logs, still getting an exception.
Also tried placing everything inside the bridge network. Nothing worked for me, though the DAG passes.

Also tried adding:

```
    image: apache/airflow
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - scheduler
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
    - 8793:8793
    command: worker
```

Did not work for me

Comment: What happens here is that the web server can not find the file of the log. The default path for the logs is at /opt/airflow/logs. In this case the log is being created on one container and tiring to be read it on an other container. To solve this you can simply mount a volume for the logs directory so that all the airflow containers have access to the logs file, as the dags file but for logs. Something like  - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose worker log-server port (worker_log_server_port setting in airflow.cfg, 8793 by default) in docker-compose, like:

```
worker:
  image: apache/airflow
  ...
  ports:
    - 8793:8793
```

Comment: @peter 

worker:
    image: apache/airflow
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - scheduler
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
    - 8793:8793
    command: worker

Comment: Edited the question as well.

Comment: in the OP from the docker compose config, looks like you don't have a worker though, i'm guessing you're using a LocalExecutor, so exposing the ports should be on the scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach I've seen a few folks use when running the `scheduler` and `webserver` in their own containers and using `LocalExecutor` (which I'm guessing is the case here):

1. Mount a host log directory as a volume into both the `scheduler` and `webserver` containers:

```
    volumes:
        - /location/on/host/airflow/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
```

2. Make sure the user within the airflow containers (usually `airflow`) has permissions to read and write that directory. If the permissions are wrong you will see an error like the one in your post.

This probably won't scale beyond `LocalExecutor` usage though.